# Bash script: get real remote (mosh+ssh) IP

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I'm using [Mosh](https://mosh.org/) + GNU Screen for most of my remote work. I'm also moving to location during the week (with different IP addresses) and this setup keeps everything running like a charm. There is one wish I have.

I'd like to have the ping speed from the server to the client as a value in the Screen statusbar.

For this I wrote a simple script which does that:

```
`ping -q -c 1 `who am i | egrep -o "\([^\)]+\)" | egrep -o "[0-9-]+{4}" | sed "s/\-/\./g"` | grep 'rtt min' | cut -d / -f 5 | cut -f 1 -d .
```

The problem is that when I go to a different location, mosh reconnects, but `who am i` command doesn't return my real IP anymore.

My question:

**Is there a robust command which will return the IP address of the client currently connected using mosh/ssh?**

---

**Update:**

This seems to work:

```
ping -q -c 1 `last | grep $USER | grep "still logged in" | egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | head -n 1` | grep 'rtt min' | cut -d / -f 5 | cut -f 1 -d .
```

Have to test is with more locations.

Comment: If you found an answer, please fill it to the answer field below, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm found this works:

```
ping -q -c 1 `last | grep $USER | grep "still logged in" | egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | head -n 1` | grep 'rtt min' | cut -d / -f 5 | cut -f 1 -d .
```

Last-command shows your 'current' remote ip.